# What is the difference between two Credential use options "VPN and apps" vs "Wifi" when installing a custom certificate on an Android emulator?

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, emulation

I'm trying to install a Charles Certificate on an Android emulator and I noticed that there are two Credential use options: "VPN and apps" and "Wi-Fi".

[image]

I've tried looking around for explanations regarding to the two options, but the one I've found simply say "pick one that fits your use case."
What is the difference between the two options? Which one should a developer pick?

Answer (score 42):

The `WiFi` option is for authentication WiFi networks, while `VPN and apps` is for authenticating certificates for SSL/TLS communication for apps including the browser.

I can also confirm that `VPN and apps` is the right choice for proxying HTTPS requests for an Android device in Charles.

> You can use digital certificates to identify your device for a variety of purposes, including VPN or Wi-Fi network access as well as authentication to servers by apps such as Email or Chrome. If you plan to use certificates for Wi-Fi authentication, be sure to select the Wi-Fi option from the menu described below.

Source: https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2844832?hl=en