# Charles proxy to connect to localhost from SSL App

Tags: android, proxy, charles-proxy

Overview:

- I have a Android App that points to some remote https server
- I have a Rails app on localhost:3000
- I want to direct trafic from the app to my localhost

Details:

1. My machine IP is `192.168.0.16`
2. I have Charles Proxy setup on port `8888`
3. On the Android phone I have configured the Wifi connection to have a manual proxy to `192.168.0.16:8888`
4. On the Android phone I have installed the SSL root cert via `chls.pro/ssl`, added to `VPN and apps` (as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/33113392/119790)
5. Charles->Access Control Settings has my Android IP `192.168.0.15` listed
6. Charles->SSL Proxying Settings has location: `*remoteserver.com:443`
7. Charles->Map Remote

   - from: `https`, `my.remoteserver.com`, `443`
   - to: `http`, `localhost`, `3000`
8. When I use the app Charles shows `Status: Connected to remote host`, and nothing more
9. On my localhost I have a rails server

   ```
   $ rails server
   ...
   Listening on localhost:3000, CTRL+C to stop
   ```
10. When I use the app nothing is ever logged (I can curl localhost and it logs that)
11. If I stop the Rails server then Charles shows `Status: Failure`, `Response code: 503 Error`
12. So it connects, but fails to get a response?

rails server running

[image: rails server running]

rails server not running

[image: rails server not running]

System:

- Android v7.1.2
- Charles v4.2.1
- OSX v10.13.3

Comment: were you able to find a solution?